# Hacer un where en FireBase con Ionic 3

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

Tengo mi BD en firebase pero quiero hacer un where (se que no hay WHERE en una BD NoSQL pero habra alguna funcion de busqueda), como un login es decir si ingreso el usuario y la contraseña me trae los datos correspondientes de un registro.

> Esta es mi BD en firebase:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Un Ejemplo:**

> Cuando yo envie el `email` y `telefono` a `tb01_usuario` me traiga los
>   datos correspondientes si los parametros coinciden:
>
> Actualmente lo estoy haciendo solo con el el ID que es similar al campo telefono, pero necesito hacerlo con los dos campos que estan dentro de cada registro, espero me entiendan

```
verifica_usuario(telefono: string) {

    email = email;
    telefono = telefono;

    let promesa = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      //this.items = afDB.list('/cuisines');
      this.af.list('/tb01_usuario/' + telefono)
        .subscribe(data => {
          if (data.length === 0) {
            //clave no es correcta
            resolve(false);
          } else {
            //clave correcta
            this.telefono = telefono;
            this.guardar_storage();
            resolve(true);
          }
        });
    })
      .catch(error => console.log("ERROR en promesa Service: " + JSON.stringify(error)));

    return promesa;
  }
```

Comment: Utiliza el método `.object` en lugar de `.list`. Lo que quieres que te retorne la consulta es un objeto.

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo una consulta como mando 2 parametros a esta funcion this.af.list('/tb01_usuario/' + telefono) es decir si le queiro mandar el telefono y el email solo lo concateno con el '+'?

Answer (score 1):

Como tal el Where no Existe en Firebase, ya que la base de datos esta en JSON, esto quiere decir que es una base de datos NoSQL, en donde solo podrás consultar basado en clave = valor. Te anexo la [documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data?hl=es-419) de las consultas disponibles que puedes hacer.

Y lo que podrías hacer, es primero obtener toda la lista de usuarios, y después filtrar con la función **equalTo**.

```
this.user = this.af.list('/tb01_usuario/');
this.user.equalTo('email');
```

Por otro lado te comento que si creas manualmente los usuarios en la base de datos de firebase, no se esta generando un **ID** que firebase asigna a cada nodo cuando creas el usuario desde alguna aplicación por ejemplo IONIC. 
Tómalo en cuenta no vaya ser que te cause problemas después, ademas que ese ID puede ayudarte a mejorar tus filtros o consultas.

Comment: inentente con esto Pero nada.                                                                                      `this.af.list('/tb01_usuario/' + telefono, {
        query: {
          orderByChild: 'telefono',
          equalTo: telefono
        }`